# make a button that moves image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to make a button that moves my image one frame height up and if the button is pushed again move the image one frame height back down.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/140/72197925.png/
(Illustration of the solution)

I am trying to use as little code as possible.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01bear.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];   
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5760, 1);

[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[window addSubview:scrollView];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

on button's touchUpInside event you need to change the:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(X,Y);//required value to scroll the scrollview
```

if you only want the imageview to move, you can use:

```
[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(X,Y)];//required value
```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

Are you using the scroll view for other things, or just to get your image to move?

Do you want your image view to animate up, then down, or move suddenly?

A scroll view is awfully complex if all you want to do is have your view animate up, then down. To do that, you should look at the UIView class method animateWithDuration:animations: and it's variations.